# Define $a_1 = 1, a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} \cos(a_n)$ Show it is cauchy

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Define $a_1 = 1, a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\cos(a_n)$ Show it is cauchy.
Hint: use the mean value theorem applied to $\cos(x)$ to show $|a_{n+1} - a_n|$ decreases geometrically fast.

attempt:

all i have as an attempt is: $$|a_{n+1} - a_n| = \left|\frac{1}{2}\right| |\cos(a_n) - \cos(a_{n-1})|$$

I am not sure how to use the MVT. I know that $$\frac{|\cos(a_n) - \cos(a_{n-1})|}{|a_n - a_{n-1}|} = f'(c)$$  but how can that help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:
$$
\frac{|a_{n+1}-a_n|}{|a_{n} - a_{n-1}|}= \frac{\frac12|\cos(a_n) - \cos(a_{n-1})|}{|a_n - a_{n-1}|}  \overset{\text{MVT}}{=} \frac12\cdot \sin(c) \leq \frac12
$$
For some $c$ between $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$. Note that this means that $\sin(c)$ is also positive. We have thus shown that $|a_{n+1} - a_n|$ is at most half of $|a_n - a_{n-1}|$ for any $n$, which is what we were asked to prove.

Comment: I take this is because $|sin(c)| \leq 1$?

Comment: @dc3rd Exactly. Of course, you can get a _much_ sharper bound once you notice that $\sin(c)<c$ for positive $c$, but that goes beyond what is asked for, so I deemed it unnecessary.

Comment: How could you establish a sharper bound? Bcause when fiddling with the sequence before posing the question I noticed the same thing occuring with the original cos(x), but I could not verify my claim.

Comment: @dc3rd I overestimated how quickly the sequence converged when I wrote the above comment. But still, there is a small modification you can do to get a moderately better bound: you can say that $\sin(c) < c< \max(a_{n-1}, a_n) < \frac12$, so the difference between the terms decreases by a factor of less than $0.25$ each time (compared to $0.5$ in my answer above). In reality, the sequence approaches something close to $0.45$, and $\sin(0.45) \approx 0.435$, so eventually, the difference between terms decreases by a factor of less than $0.22$.